# PHP Swagger OpenApi Generic Type

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I'm using `zircote/swagger-php` for annotations to generate swagger for my php WebApi.
I have my generic model `HttpResponse`, it has 2 common properties (`messages` and `statusCode`) but `data` is generic and has different type for every endpoint.
I'm trying to annote it via `zircote/swagger-php` and use different model for this `data` property for every endpoint. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Right now I'm trying something like below, but its giving me first of those `anyOf` to every request instead allow me specific which one i want.

```
/**
 * @OA\Schema()
 */
class HttpResponse
{
    /**
     * @OA\Property(anyOf={
     *          @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/HolidayRequestSpecificInput"),
     *          @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/AvailableHolidayDatesApiModel")
     *       })
     */
    public $data;
    /**
     * @OA\Property(type="array", @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Message"))
     */
    public $messages;
    /**
     * @OA\Property(ref="#/components/schemas/HttpResponseType")
     */
    public $statusCode;

    public function __construct($statusCode = HttpResponseType::Ok, $data = null)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->messages = [];
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
    }

    public function addMessages($messages)
    {
        foreach ($messages as $msg)
            array_push($this->messages, $msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be that you should use `oneOf` rather than `anyOf`.

However, this way things are set up right now each endpoint would return `HttpResponse` with a choice of data structures which is not ideal.

Better, IMHO, would be to have each endpoint define exactly the data that it returns (unless I am misunderstanding your code).

In that case I'd suggest you split the response schema into a base and explicit `@OA\Response` definitions for each endpoint.

The downside might be that the annotations do not reflect exactly your code. However, the spec would reflect more explicit the data structures returned by the endpoints.

```
/**
 * @OA\Schema()
 */
class BaseResponse
{
    /**
     * @OA\Property(type="array", @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Message"))
     */
    public $messages;

    /**
     * @OA\Property(ref="#/components/schemas/HttpResponseType")
     */
    public $statusCode;
}

/**
 * @OA\Schema()
 */
class HolidayRequestSpecificInput{
    /**
     * @OA\Property()
     */
    public $location;

}

/**
 * @OA\Get(path="/holiday",
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response="200",
 *         description="OK",
 *         @OA\JsonContent(
 *             allOf={
 *                 @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/BaseResponse"),
 *                 @OA\Schema(
 *                     @OA\Property(property="data", ref="#/components/schemas/HolidayRequestSpecificInput")
 *                 )
 *             }
 *         )
 *     )
 * )
 */
class Controller{}
```

Comment: Tbh i don't like duplicate code if not needed, but right now I don't see any better solution that you just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use a discriminator as described here :
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/